# How to reduce whitespace from JSON on the command line without installing a tool

Tags: json, command-line

I've used `python -m json.tool` to pretty print JSON and check for errors for years. It is nice because it works on just about any system with python installed. How can I **take out** unnecessary whitespace that JSON ignores (i.e. not in string values) without installing on mac/linux/bsd/unix systems without installing anything special? Answers that work on recent baseline mac, freebsd and debian/ubuntu would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a code golfer but I puzzled out this solution which makes a nice alias with some escaping:

```
python '-cimport json,sys;json.dump(json.load(sys.stdin),sys.stdout,separators=(",", ":"))'
```